# Disable GTT on amdgpu?

Tags: kernel, memory, amd-graphics, amd, kernel-parameters

How can I disable GTT on amdgpu?

According to https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.20/gpu/amdgpu.html, adding `amdgpu.gttsize=0` should work but that has no effect.

The reason why I am asking is, that my Vega 8 graphics (of my AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 5850U cpu) already has 4GB VRAM and takes another 4GB of GTT. As the GTT memory is cut off from my "regular" 16 GB memory but I mainly use my CPU over my GPU (compiling, databases...), I only can use 12GB of it.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The only thing I could do was reduce the "UMA Frame Buffer" size in the BIOS to 1GB (which appears to be the minimum). It was set to auto but was taking more than 5GB which lead my linux OS to have only 11GB of available ram (from 16GB)

Comment: Probably just a checkup: Did you run `update-grub` after adding that `gttsize` to `/etc/default/grub`?

Comment: Also, did you rule out your UEFI BIOS settings?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid your integrated vga has no ram. Based on https://askgeek.io/en/cpus/AMD/Ryzen-7-PRO-5850U : Transistor count 4,940 million ....
Try the vramlimit instead of gtt.

Comment: It has some allocated by BIOS

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the CPU can use the GTT memory area as long as the GPU puts no data there. So just don't run graphics intensive programs and your CPU can use all the memory. See also what I wrote here:
https://kolahilft.de/2023/09/vram-and-memory-for-integrated-graphics-with-linux/
If you have no use for GPU performance on that system, you might even lower the vram to a minimal value in the BIOS. Even if you spontaneously use the integrated GPU (CPU+GPU), it can use the GTT memory area at the same speed as the vram memory area.
In short: with an integrated GPU the GTT memory can do everything the vram can do, but GTT can be used by the CPU if the GPU is not using it.

P.S.
If you really want to lower the GTT size. Did you try to set it to a low value like `amdgpu.gttsize=64` (64 MiB)? That worked for me. But I really recommend you to lower the vram size in BIOS and to leave the gttsize untouched.

Related: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/p17pvw/disable_gtt_on_amdgpu/